Maximize matrix trace norm $\| A - B \|$ for two positive semidefinite matrices A and B subjected to $A \leq C$ and $B \leq C$
The problem can be phrased as,
\begin{align}
\text{maximize}\;\;& \| A - B \|\\[2pt]
\text{subject to}\;\;& 0 \leq A \leq  C\\[2pt]
&0 \leq  B \leq  C\\
\end{align}
where only C is given.
$0 \leq A \leq  C$ means matrices $C-A$ and $A$ are positive semidefinite. Matrix trace norm for M is given by $\|M\|=tr(\sqrt{MM^{*}})$.
While I tried to attack the problem from sub-additivity of trace norm and semidefinite cone perspectives, little results are achieved. From Weyl's inequality, I'm able to prove that when additional constraints, i.e., $A-B \leq 0$ or $A-B \geq 0$, are introduced, max $\| A - B \|$ = $\| C \|$. However, I'm still struggling on the case where $A - B$ is indefinite.
I would like to know whether the above optimization can be solved analytically, i.e., whether it is true that the answer to the above questions is max $\| A - B \|$ = $\| C \|$. If so, any hint regarding the prove/disprove will be appreciated.

We have $\max_{\,\pmb{0} \leq \pmb{A},\pmb{B} \leq \pmb{C} } \| \pmb{A} \!-\! \pmb{B} \| = \| \pmb{C} \|$ without additional constraints.
$ \because$) Note that $ \| \pmb{M} \|  = \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{M})$ for $\pmb{M} \geq \pmb{0}$. We have that:
$$
\| \pmb{A} \!-\! \pmb{B} \| \leq \| \pmb{A} \| + \| \pmb{B} \|  = \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{A}) + \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{B})\,,
$$
and
$$
\| \pmb{A} \!-\! \pmb{B} \|  \leq \| \pmb{C} \!-\! \pmb{A} \| + \| \pmb{C} \!-\! \pmb{B} \|  = \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{C} \!-\! \pmb{A}) + \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{C} \!-\! \pmb{B})\,,
$$
since $\pmb{C}\!-\!\pmb{A}, \pmb{C}\!-\!\pmb{B} \geq \pmb{0}$.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\| \pmb{A} \!-\! \pmb{B} \|   & \leq  \frac{1}{2} \Big(\mathrm{tr}(\pmb{C} \!-\! \pmb{A}) + \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{C} \!-\! \pmb{B})\Big) + \frac{1}{2} \Big( \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{A}) + \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{B}) \Big)\\
& =  \mathrm{tr}(\pmb{C}) = \| \pmb{C} \|\,.
\end{align*}

Thank you so much! That's really a beautiful prove. I was able to get the first inequality using sub-additivity but didn’t have enough insight to get the second and the combination of the two. Thank you again, will definitely acknowledge if it ends up used in my research. (Unfortunately since I'm new I cannot vote your answer now.)

Glad it helped! Wishing you success in your research journey.
